# UIButton to move along with keyboard. The position resets when user presses a key

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikeyboard

I have a function that moves the UIButton that is at the bottom of the screen with the keyboard. The problem is, when the user presses a key (Begins to write in the text field) the button goes back down.

I tried to set `addBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`

This works only if my Xcode has the main.storyboard set as the simulator, otherwise it breaks the constraints. At first I thought it's just a Xcode 9 bug but then I uploaded a bundle on iTunes Connect and asked my girlfriend to download the app through TestFlight and indeed the constraints were messed up when setting the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`

```
func bindToKeyboard () {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame , object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillChange(_ notification : NSNotification) {
    let duration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
    let startingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let endingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

    let deltaY = endingFrame.origin.y - startingFrame.origin.y

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
    },completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Try to use keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide rather than the keyboardWillChange notification. 

Alternatively, looks at accessory views for keyboards that make the animation easier to manage and keyboards show and disappear.

Comment: The current logic is keyboardWillChange because I got 2 textfields, one numeric and one alphabetic so keyboards are different, it need to move the button along with the keyboard changes. 
I tried what you said anyway and it still not working, when I press a key on the keyboard, the button goes back to where it has its constraints

Answer (score 0):

OK so after 3 hours of fighting with this bug I disabled the autoresizingmasks and I created an **outlet** for the **bottom constraint**.

After every animation I updated that constraint with **deltaY**

so my code looks like this now

```
func bindToKeyboard () {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame , object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillChange(_ notification : NSNotification) {
    let duration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
    let startingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let endingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

    let deltaY = endingFrame.origin.y - startingFrame.origin.y

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
    },completion: nil)


    btc.constant -= deltaY
}
```

What a pleasant saturday night! I love programming!